# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch for HABTM in rails

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have got two models Zipcode & Plan

```
class Zipcode < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'code'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :plans, :class_name => "Plan", 
     :join_table => "plans_zipcodes", :foreign_key => "code"
end

class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :zipcodes, :class_name => "Zipcode", 
    :join_table => "plans_zipcodes", :association_foreign_key => "code"
end
```

I am using the field **code**(type string) as the primary key in zipcodes table. In the join table(plans_zipcodes) I have plan_id & code fields.

Now when i try doing

```
plan = Plan.first
plan.zipcodes = [76546, 75001, 75667]
```

It gives me this

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Zipcode(#90410810) expected, got Fixnum(#72919920)
```

Please help fix this.